# How can I do the action "Android Tools > Rename Application Package" via command line

Tags: android

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862138/how-can-i-change-the-application-package-name-for-an-android-app-via-command-lin/9862320#9862320) but the answer does not perform a refactoring of the code as `Android Tools > Rename Application Package` does. I need this command line to include it in a script to create the three APKs of my application: free, demo and paid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution would be to make use of Android Library Projects.

Put your common code into a library and wrap that library in a separate project for each of your other types of application.

i.e 4 projects in total. Free, Demo, Paid and Library. (Although why bother with demo as a free version could perform this purpose)

Each project could then be built without any refactoring (which could be dangerous)

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects) for full details.

Another option would be have only one project and utilise [in app billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html) to upgrade to a paid status. This has the advantage of you only having to maintain one app and speaking from experience, users will be less confused as to which app they want