# Android project R.java file

Tags: java, android

My question is if there is already a way to automate the creation of an app? For example a script that changes the package name in all necessary places? If that isn't possible I want to ask if there is a way to change the location of the generated R.java file?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the location of `R.java` file.

This is how you can rename your package name to all the places at one go.

1. Go to `AndroidManifest.xml`.
2. Put your cursor in the package name (don't select it).
3. Press `shift+F6`, you will get a popup window, select Rename package.
4. Enter your new name and select Refactor.

**Update:** This is how you can rename the package name using an ant build, a ref to [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862138/how-can-i-change-the-application-package-name-for-an-android-app-via-command-lin)

Comment: Thank you for that qick answer but i am thinking more about not opening the projekt. I have a script that already changes the app_icon and changes relevant values in files now i would like to change the packagename with the same script. I can change the packagename in the android manifest which isn't a problem. But i dont want to have to change import packagename.R; in every class.

Comment: @MaxGierlachowski: Is it an `Ant` build script?