# Package name change of android studio project using command prompt and gradle

Tags: android

I have an android studio project. I made a signed apk of it using command line gradlew assembleRelease. But the problem is I want to make the apk with different package name for each time building. For doing this, I have to change the package name of the application from command prompt. Is there any solution to make this ?

Comment: you can change the package name by right-click > Refactor >rename

Comment: i need to make it using command prompt

Comment: I wish this could help [change package name using command line ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862138/how-can-i-change-the-application-package-name-for-an-android-app-via-command-lin)