# how can rename android application package name with command line or tasks?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to know :How can I change the application package name for an Android app via command line or using task?
i don't want to change it with android studio.
I have used [How can I change the application package name for an Android app via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9862138/how-can-i-change-the-application-package-name-for-an-android-app-via-command-lin)
but i can't use it

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: in above link i tried with android update project that can't change package name with it,and i don't know that how can use -Dpackage.manifest.name=value .i don't find any example for this.

Comment: I don't find any example for change package name and logo in project with cmd or task.:-(